# Why does hitting ESCAPE prevent an <iframe> from loading?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, web

I had a really weird bug in my application where an `<iframe>` wasn't loading if it was added to the DOM by hitting ESCAPE.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { toggled: true }
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        // Uncomment the next line to make the video work when hitting ESC
        // e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({ toggled: false })
      }
    })
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ toggled: !this.state.toggled })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.toggled
          ? <div>Hit ESC to show the video</div>
          : (
            <div>
              <div><button onClick={this.toggle}>Hide video</button></div>
              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lUOK2ZpjvaM" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}
```

[Demo on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/docofeyewa/2/edit?js,output).

What you're seeing here is a simple React app that shows an embedded YouTube-Video when you hit ESCAPE. There is something I don't understand about this though: The `<iframe>` only loads if I `preventDefault()` on the `keydown` event.

Why is this necessary? I've observed this behaviour in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: An IFrame is basically a browser inside a your page.  If you go to a page while loading, and hit escape, it will stop..   So this is what's happening here.  Maybe a better key than ESCAPE,  might be an idea.  Or doing your preventDefault() is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of the browsers - pressing `escape` will stop the page from loading.

E.g. in chrome:
https://superuser.com/questions/162660/how-do-you-stop-a-webpage-from-loading-in-google-chrome#answer-162661

An `iframe` will load another complete webpage inside the current page, therefore all keypress actions for a normal webpage still apply to the `iframe`.

You are correct that you can prevent this by using event.preventDefault() on keydown. It would be a good idea to only call preventDefault if the key *is* the escape key otherwise you will block the default actions for all other keys.

Inside your keydown event you should add something like:

```
if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: How does stopping the page from loading help load the iFrame? Can you please explain?

Comment: @koolkat The "escape" keypress would generally halt a page load. Preventing that default action allows the iframe to continue loading.